# moving file then log everything

Tags: php

I used `rename()` to move files from source dir to destination dir. Can I have any of your suggestion, if how can I log the process during the process. I am thinking it would be inside this:

```
while(false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
    if(is_file($src . '/' . $file)) {
        rename($src . '/' . $file, $dest . '/' . $file);
    }
}
```

The log can simply contain the successful transfer of each file or if any error occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Rename returns bool, you can use that

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
$logfilename = 'log.txt'; // Or whatever you call it
while(false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
    if(is_file($src . '/' . $file)) {
        if(rename($src . '/' . $file, $dest . '/' . $file)){
            file_put_contents($logfilename, 'Successfully renamed '.
            '"'.$src . '/' . $file.'" to "'.$dest . '/' . $file.'"'.PHP_EOL,
                FILE_APPEND);
        }else{
            file_put_contents($logfilename, 'Failed to rename'.
            '"'.$src . '/' . $file.'" to "'.$dest . '/' . $file.'"'.PHP_EOL,
                FILE_APPEND);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks PaulPRO, however is there any built-in function in PHP which holds the specific error if like in this the rename() failed to rename the file? It's because I want to include it in the log. Thanks.

Comment: @Dee, not, unfortunately there is no function built into PHP lof the form `rename_error();` The only data you have is whether it succeeded or failed, which you get from the return value of `rename()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$p=fopen('php://stderr','w');
while(false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
  if(is_file($src . '/' . $file)) {
    if(rename($src . '/' . $file, $dest . '/' . $file)) {
       @fputs($p, "OK - mv $src/$file $dest/$file\n");
    } else {
       @fputs($p, "ERROR - - mv $src/$file $dest/$file\n");
    }
  }
}
@fclose($p);
```